# Kinematics:Accelerating Elevator Question

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

Consider a scenario where an elevator is moving up with constant acceleration 'a'.
If a stone is thrown from it will the stone also possess an acceleration 'a'?

Because i know that if we throw a stone from an elevator moving with uniform velocity the stone also acquires that velocity,so what will be the case with uniform acceleration.

Comment: If you consider the case from ground frame , the acceleration will be $g$ , as the moment it is released it has no force from elevator . But , in elevator frame , the relative acceleration will be $g+a$ ...